# Failed to connect to SafariDriver. Selenium 2.44.0 run via a daemon on OSX Yosemite & Safari 8

Tags: selenium, webdriver, daemon, osx-yosemite, safaridriver

Im currently on Yosemite and Safari 8.

I keep getting this error:

`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10161 ms
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'TODIGWS000993.local', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:51)
    ... 14 more
18:42:43.408 WARN - Exception: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10161 ms
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'TODIGWS000993.local', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver`

I am setting up my own grid and I'm using the standalone jar files (2.44.0). I am running the hub and node via daemons using launchd and a .plist file for each respectively.
All other browsers (FF and Chrome) load and run the tests fine.

I followed the instructions listed by

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7933#c33

and successfully, manually, installed webdriver extension into the safari 8 browser

Initially when running selenium jars via daemons this did not work. But when i stopped the daemons and ran the jars (with the same arguments) using the logged in user the safari driver error went away and the safari browser loaded and ran the test.

I have tried with the argument

```
-Dwebdriver.safari.noinstall=true
```

but still no progress.

Have also set the daemon to have the same env variables as the logged in user that did successfully run the test but this also did not work.

Basically, the same command works when ran via the logged in user but not via a daemon. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /usr/lib/selenium-code/osx/node_config.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/lib/selenium/chromedriver
```

Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'TODIGWS000993.local', ip: 'xxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
safari 8

Here are the logs from the safari driver:

```
18:40:41.78 [safaridriver.extension] Creating global session...
18:40:41.78 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Registering new tab
18:40:41.78 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Set command tab to hncoksu5irc9
18:40:41.78 [safaridriver.extension] Creating debug driver...
18:40:41.78 [safaridriver.extension] Waiting for connect command...
18:43:04.20 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Registering new tab
18:43:04.20 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Tab opened: wgoy5x4bmbnw
18:43:04.34 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Ignoring open window event
18:43:04.34 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Deleting entry for tab wgoy5x4bmbnw
18:43:04.89 [safaridriver.extension.Server] [wi8mei4r9u3q] Executing command: newSession
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue: createDriver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10342 ms

To get it resolved after trying some things, I registered myself at the Apple Site for “Safari Developer Program” and generated a certificate to use in Safari. Installed the certificate in my Key-chain and added the Safari Extension to the browser.

Can refer the site for steps to proceed: https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/working-with-safari-driver/

I am using software configurations like:
Selenium: selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar
Safari: 7.1.3
Mac: 10.9.5

Even tested on latest Selenium 2.44.0 and Safari 8.0. This approach works.

Comment: Is this some customized extension created ? I am using the extension which comes with safari webdriver jar. That does not requires cert.